# Не могу сделать спойлер ;(

Tags: javascript, html

**Привязка js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/js.js"></script>
```

**Button**

```
<button onclick="showText(this)">Read More...</button>
```

**JS**

```
function showText (el) {
    if(el.previousElementSibling.clientHeight == 80) {
        el.previousElementSibling.style.height = "100%";
        el.innerHTML = "ShowLess...";
    } else {
        el.previousElementSibling.style.height = "80px";
        el.innerHTML = "Read More...";
    }
```

Ошибка в консоле:

> js.js:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input 3index.html:53
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: showText is not definedonclick @
>   index.html:53 9index.html:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: showText is not
>   definedonclick @ index.html:77

Comment: Ошибка в консоле js.js:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
3index.html:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: showText is not definedonclick @ index.html:53
9index.html:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: showText is not definedonclick @ index.html:77

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде все верно, за исключением того, что в конце JS не хватает закрывающейся фигурной скобки.

```js
function showText(el) {
  if (el.previousElementSibling.clientHeight == 80) {
    el.previousElementSibling.style.height = "100%";
    el.innerHTML = "ShowLess...";
  } else {
    el.previousElementSibling.style.height = "80px";
    el.innerHTML = "Read More...";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red">ololo</div>
<button onclick="showText(this)">Read More...</button>
```

Так же было бы не плохо проверять, что *previousElementSibling* существует

```
if(!el.previousElementSibling) {
   return
}
```

Comment: Скобка в конце всё решила -_- Пол часа сидел, не мог понять... Спасибо.

Comment: @bluray отлично, ну тогда примите как ответ ;)